# Why does Arch Linux keep Windows headphone mute

Tags: arch-linux, windows, audio, alsa

I have Windows 7 installed, and headphones work perfectly.
Few days ago, I installed Arch Linux along with Win7.
This issue appears with gnome/xfce4/openbox. Perhaps it is not related to desktop environment

My headphones work fine under Arch Linux but:

1. When I turn to Win7 from Arch Linux, headphones stop working.
2. When I reboot Win7 twice, headphone works.
3. When I use `halt -p`, from Arch Linux and reboot to Win7, headphone
   works fine.

I am using plain headphones(not usb headphone). Here is my device

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 05)

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Redwood HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5000 Series] [1002:aa60]
```

Comment: Acer 4820T, HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic

Comment: Are you using a USB headphone, or just a plain headphone that is connected via TRS phone connector to your sound card/mainboard? If it's the latter, it's not your headphone that is not working, but the sound card itself.

Comment: Also, please post the output of `lcpci -nn` so we know exactly what type of sound card you are using. If you are using a USB headphone, please post the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich I add hardware info to the question, could you just have a look at that?

Comment: What desktop environment? Which sound subsystem are you using?

Comment: @strugee This issue appears  on gnome/xfce4/openbox

Answer (score 0):

I can not say for sure what the problem is but after doing a little research I do have some suggestions:

**No-1.** It could be that you're using the wrong default audio device as it's probably defaulting to HDMI. Disable HDMI audio or just set another default device.

**No-2.** It could be you are using the wrong sound codec in the modprobe conf.
You might find something about that here → https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1273556#p1273556 .

**No-3.** Check to see if anything is muted. Try using alsamixer to unmute everything.

**No-4.** Try installing OSS = "Open Sound System". I know nothing much about it but have read other people with same type of problem say they fixed it with this. More info on OSS.

**Here →** http://www.opensound.com/

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happening to me until I found out what was the problem.
Open your Audio Mixer and click the Select Controls button.  There you will find several options but there is one that says Auto-Mute Mode.  Check that and you will have a new tab where you can disable the auto-mute mode.

Comment: What does the `audio mixer` actually means ? Windows mixer or gnome mixer or alsa mixer or something else ?

Comment: @jilen Since the problem occurs in Windows, probably the Windows Audio Mixer :)